# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I have simplified my problem. I only want to get coordinates using android mobile. The web page is working fine on desktop but on android mobile its not working. My location is turned On.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    alert("Working"); // This alert is shown but coordinates are not displayed
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried implementing error messages to see what's going on? Read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) and scroll down to "Handling Errors and Rejections"

Comment: on desktop i didnt get any errors, on mobile i am not able to open console to view any error msgs,

Comment: You don't need to open console. Extract errors into HTML document like it's said in link i provided.

Comment: i tried to find my location using this url from my mobile,
``` 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation
```
it didnt shown any messages

Comment: Use [this link for geolocation instead](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error)

Comment: Thanks Folks, i used @Vepthy way and it helped me lot, basically i was trying to fetch global variable inside that success function which wasn't accessible. 
once it is fixed, my issue is resolved. Thanks once again